# Do you need to create a private backing-variable as soon as you have get/set logic?

Tags: c#, properties, c#-3.0

If you create a property in C#, AFIK, you don't need a private backing-variable if you simply use get/set, taking advantage of C# 3.0 auto-implemented properties:

```
...
public int Age {get;set;}
```

However, let's say you want to put a touch of logic into the Age property and let it accept values only greater than 18. At this point, is it necessary to create a private variable? Is there a way around that?

Comment: Actually technically it is not necessary to create a private variable - the variable can also be protected or public. And there is a way around it - by using a tool that changes the bytecode later and adds the validation logic by external rules (like an attribute) by rewriting the bytecode post compile. Such tools exist ;)

Comment: Yes you normally need it. But there are still ways around it, like making you own class inheriting from `int` and only accepting values above 18. But that is not really worth the work, just to hide the private variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, let's say you want to put a touch of logic into the Age
>   property and let it accept values only greater than 18.  **At this
>   point, is it necessary to create a private variable?**

Yes. You will need a backing field.

> you don't need a private backing-variable if you simply use get/set,

For auto implemented properties, compiler will add the backing field.

See: [Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required
>   in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following
>   example, **the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field**
>   that can only be accessed through the property's get and set
>   accessors.

Your property would look like:

```
private int _age;

public int Age
{
    get { return _age; }
    set
    {
        if (_age > 18)
            _age = value;
        else
        {
            //throw exception, Show message etc 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> At this point, is it necessary to create a private variable?

well, you have to store it *somewhere* - usually a private backing variable is easiest.

You *could* use validation attributes, but those are enforced at the UI layer - it does not add any "special" logic to the setter that's used universally.

BTW the compiler creates backing variables behind-the-scenes for you anyways, so it doesn't change the low-level behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is necessary. No, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way around that?

No, there is no way around it: if your code needs to store the state of the property in a variable, and you need some logic around that variable, you need to add that variable manually.

There are only two cases when you do not need a backing variable for a property:

- Your property is calculated, and
- Your property us auto-implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to declare your own private backing field.

Just to be clear, when you use an auto-implemented property, there still *is* a private backing field, except it's generated by the compiler.

You'll need to declare it yourself if you want to add logic to the property, or if you only need either a getter or a setter, but not both.